# Black Background of screenshot

Tags: java, android, bitmap, background, screenshot

I am taking a screenshot of my activity with the following code:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.scroll);

ScrollView z = (ScrollView) view;
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(z.getChildAt(0).getWidth(),
    z.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
view.buildDrawingCache(true);
view.draw(c);

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
view.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Now the problem is that background of screen is black and original background is not visible.

[image: original activity]

[image: screenshot with black background]

Please help me how to solve this issue?

xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#a91111"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textColor="#e7e414"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:text="share" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Yahooooooooooooo"
            android:textColor="#c32aa5"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="scrolllllllll"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="#c32aa5"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Guessing the scroll view has no background, and that you see the white windowBackground. by drawing the view, the window background is not drawn

Comment: Try setting white background to your parent layout that holds R.id.scroll, Or if R.id.scroll is your parent view then try adding background to the view from xml.

Comment: I tried by setting different background color of scroll view but still no change.

Comment: Can you share your xml code as well?

Comment: look at my xml code @zohair

Comment: setBackground to your Relative layout :)

Comment: okay I got your point..It is drawing background of layout not view..thanx..:)

Comment: give one answer...i am not able to upvote your comment